# Laravel 5.7, Moved User class, RegisterController can't find it

Tags: laravel, class

I am planning a somewhat complex Laravel application, and so I have moved the default `User.php` class from `App\User` to `App\Http\Models\Users\User`.

[Paths & Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jDv1.png)

I have changed the paths appropriately in the code (please see screenshot).

Unfortunately, I am still getting this error:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSQyh.png)

I have not changed composer.json, nor any other files than `config/auth.php` and `app/Http/Controllers/RegisterController.php`. Also, I am unable to locate any other files in the project that are using `App\User` (other than RegisterController).

I have updated and migrated the file for the users table.

I'm probably missing something obvious, so please be kind.  ;-)

Can someone point out what I'm missing?

Comment: Did you renamed the namespace on the `User.php` class?

Answer (score 0):

The path must coincide with the namespace to the file be loaded as expected.

So if your path is

`app\Http\Models\Users\User.php`

Your class namespace must be:

`namespace App\Http\Models\Users;`

Note that the `App` on the namespace must be in CamelCase. Otherwise it will not work.

Comment: It *is* `namespace App\Http\Models\Users;`, both at the top of the class file, and in the doc block for the `create` method.

Answer (score 0):

only 4 files contains App\User class reference

- app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController
- config/app.php
- config/services.php
- database/factories/UserFactory.php

Answer (score 0):

The namespace in my `User` class was incorrect (missing 'Http'):

Wrong: `namespace App\Models\Users`

Right: `namespace App\Http\Models\Users`

Thank you all for your suggestions, especially [@elias-soares](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3429323/elias-soares)!